# How to apply Kotlin JVM gradle plugin from a buildSrc (shared) gradle script?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, buildsrc

I'm trying to apply a plugin from a shared gradle script.

in my shared gradle script I have the following code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    }
}
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
```

In the other builds I try and do

```
apply from: "shared.gradle"
...
```

If I run any gradle task, I get the following error:

```
 Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' not found
```

I've tried multiple ids instead of "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm":
like "org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper" and "kotlin"...
none works!

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, what fixed it for me was adding this on **buildSrc/build.gradle.kts**

```
dependencies {
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.10")
}
```

And then, on my conventions script **buildScr/src/main/kotlin/application-conventions.gradle.kts** I just removed the version

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}
```

Comment: You can also use `kotlin("jvm")` in your conventions script instead of `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")` to keep it kotlin friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath for kotlin Plugin is `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper`

Comment: I already tried that...